# Jq returning null value for nested key in my shell script

Tags: linux, variables, curl, jq

I am trying to output the value for nested json key but for some reason I get null value.

```
    SP=$(curl --proxy ...my apicall)
    declare -A prop_map=(
                ["ID"] = "tagInfo.id"
    )

    for key in ${!prop_map[@]}; do
    pn=${prop_map["$key"]}
    val=$(jq -r --arg e "$pn" '.[$e]' <<< 
    "$SP")
    echo $val
```

Curl response looks like this
{
tag info:{ id: "12"  , name:...}}

Can anyone please guide ..been stuck on this for so long

Comment: Is this your code? When I try to reproduce, I find different error messages (wrong JSON format, wrong declaration of the prop_map-Array).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: The "curl response" shown is far removed from being valid JSON, and so it might be difficult to use jq.  Also, your "for" loop needs a terminating "done".

Answer (score 1):

One of the fundamental problems with your script is that it
assumes that jq can make sense of:

```
jq -r --arg e "tagInfo.id" '.[$e]' <<< '{"tagInfo":{ "id": "12" , "name": "aname"}}'
```

Here are two workarounds:

1. Use a shell variable:

```
e="tagInfo.id"
jq -r ".[$e]" <<< '{"tagInfo":{ "id": "12" , "name": "aname"}}'
```

2. Specify the path as an array:

```
jq -r --argjson e '["tagInfo", "id"]' 'getpath($e)' <<< '{"tagInfo":{ "id": "12" , "name": "aname"}}'
```

Since (1) above is somewhat fragile, it would probably be better to go with (2).